# Git history contains so many previous commits from previously accepted PR's

Tags: git, github

My PR git history contains heaps of commits from previous PR's that have been (previously) accepted and merged. It *feels* ugly and inaccurate and noisy.

I'm expecting my PR to only contain the *new* commits I've just created, for this new custom branch.

But even though my PR lists all these previous commits (as part of this new PR), the actual file changes are my *new* commits. So the code is only my new code ... just the history is noisy spammy.

Here's what it looks like:
- Red square == my current PR which (by fluke) only contains 1x commit. (i sometimes have multiple commits per PR)
- Grey square == commits from *other* PR's, which are already merged into `master`.

[image]

So, this is what i'm doing, locally.

- Switch to `master`
- Pull `upstream master`
- Create and switch to a new branch. e.g. `fix-something`.
- Tap tap tap / fix code.
- Commit once or a few times.
- Push code to `origin fix-something`  (i can't push to upstream. only to *my* fork)
- Create a PR from my fork (`origin`) to the main repo (`upstream`).
- PR lists all these previous commits from previous PR's. Code that is changes, is only mine, though.

I thought that, when I do the first two steps, everything should be ok?

Also ... one last piece of info -> how does the PR get accepted? We always "Squash and Merge" using the GitHub website, after we've all reviewed/approved/etc.

Is the "Squash and Merge" the cause of this?

Comment: To which branch on upstream have you opened the PR?

Comment: @choroba PR opened up to `upstream master` from my `origin fix-something`

Comment: And your `fix-something` starts at the latest commit of `origin/master`, right?

Comment: I believe so. As suggested above, I switch to `master` and the pull `upstream:master` which should then make me 'up to date' with the latest commits. And -now- I start my own branch and start coding...

Comment: The culprit here may be `git pull`. My guess is it's making these merge commits.